# How would I manage to create this CLI python interface (it's pretty complex)

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setup-project

First and foremost, if someone invests the time and effort to guide me through this, I can compensate financially. I can afford $250-$500 for a full blown mentor to assist me through the project, I will do all of the programming and you would simply review the work and show me the road to success.

I need help with creating the classes, subclasses, and the file system that would run a CLI based program that has menus and takes input from the user and allows navigation, has prompts for inputs and stores inputs into some type of persistent data function, perhaps a dictionary, array, list, or even importing pickle. Im not sure. I need help with this!

My bottom line goal is to take a GUI based automation program and develop a CLI based input output python program that supports outputting user input to .txt files and stores metadata into an SQL-lite database either locally or server based.

First step is to learn the background regarding the project.

So lets get started with an introduction----

---

there is this software called Jitbit Macro Recorder that delivers a concise bundle of automation tools and does a very effective job in automation and is very simple to use for simple automation jobs and on the fly automation (like semi automated copying and pasting)

URL to visit https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/

The positives of jitbit macro recorder
Labels and Goto commands, boolean logical commands, simple actions and screen recognition allow full blown automation to occur.

The GUI is clunky with redundant repetition and mouse clicks are annoying
Large projects don't have support regarding fragmenting large scripts or decomposition
It lacks a database and supportive filing system that one would need to acheive full GUI automation

SUMMARY- Jitbit automates stuff and its easy to use until things get large and labels and goto commands are required.

Solution- reduce redundancy and GUI with a python script that combines the static syntax from jitbit, gets the dynamic variables from user from navigation logical sequence like

Main Menu -> Script Creation -> Process ID -> Subprocess ID -> Action Choice -> Parameters
We begin at the main menu where we choose to create a new script, the python script would require a process manager that tracks the user input for each action, delay, and requires a label which outputs a goto label for the script.

---

It gets extremely unorganized while developing complex scripts because there is no support of fragmenting scripts and compartmentalizing or chunking large projects into components or processes with subprocess support.

I am seeking a professional to answer this question and perhaps assist a build for this program.

Background information:
I am trying to build a python CLI.
I need have menus that prompt according to my input.
Main menu would have 4 screens to print.
Welcome to jitbit main menu
1- Script Creation
2- Script Management
3- Settings
4- Exit
If the user selects the Script Creation, i need it to start a script that allows me to build automation scripts.
It needs to create a process manager for the script that

Comment: You should use freelance websites for such requests. StackOverflow is about helping to resolve issues and problems, clarifications etc.

Comment: I've used freelancers but I end up in the same position I am in right now, which is searching for answers and putting the pieces together to complete this project. I've been down that path with no luck. I am offering incentive to someone that devotes more than just a suggestion, and perhaps a more direct line of communication than a forum, I am simply offering compensation for going above and beyond if someone has the knowledge and spare time. Sorry if I have broken any rules or if this is outside of the scope of the website, I understand the model. This answer is more than a one liner.